# Saxon 10 HE - Do I need one namespace per Java Extension Class?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I am migrating from Saxon9 to Saxon10 HE. My current XSL files contain a single namespace which points to the class where I have defined multiple functions.

I then invoke my functions using the syntax

```
common_namespace:function_name
```

With Saxon10 HE I have defined one namespace for each function as each function is declared within its own class

So with Saxon10 I am declaring each function using the name of the class.

```
functionclassname:function_name
functionclassname:function_name
functionclassname:function_name
etc...
```

This works, but it means that I cannot run any of my Saxon9 based XSL files with Saxon10 without replacing the current namespace definition (singular) with multiple namespaces (one for each function).

This maybe a limitation of Saxon10 HE but if there is anyway I can modify my Java code so that I can use my current XSL files then it would be most helpful.

Comment: What Saxon 9 version exactly are you referring to? Are you trying to change from reflexive to integrated extension functions?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the open-source Saxon version 10 HE version. I am moving from the previous open-source version 9.

My version 9 XSL style sheet would look rather like :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:c4j="http://www.commander4j.com"
    xmlns:c4j_XSLT_Ext="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/com.commander4j.Transformation.XSLTExtension"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs c4j c4j_XSLT_Ext"  version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent='yes' method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
```

A call to a function would look like

```
<dueDate><xsl:value-of select="c4j_XSLT_Ext:date_DD_MMM_YY_to_ISO_Date($due_date)" </dueDate>

<material><xsl:value-of select="c4j_XSLT_Ext:trim($code)"</material>
```

You should notice that there is only 1 namespace c4j_XSLT_Ext defined for both function calls.

My version 10 XSL looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c4j="http://www.commander4j.com"
    xmlns:c4j_XSLT_Ext="http://com.commander4j.Transformation.XSLT_Ext"
    xmlns:c4j_XSLT_Ext_trim="http://com.commander4j.Transformation.XSLT_Ext_trim"
    xmlns:c4j_XSLT_Ext_date_DD_MMM_YY_to_ISO_Date="http://com.commander4j.Transformation.XSLT_Ext_date_DD_MMM_YY_to_ISO_Date"
    exclude-result-prefixes="c4j_XSLT_Ext c4j_XSLT_Ext_nvl c4j_XSLT_Ext_date_DD_MMM_YY_to_ISO_Date"  version="2.0">
```

with a call to a function looking like

```
<dueDate><xsl:value-of select="c4j_XSLT_Ext_date_DD_MMM_YY_to_ISO_Date:date_DD_MMM_YY_to_ISO_Date($due_date)" </dueDate>

<material><xsl:value-of select="c4j_XSLT_Ext_trim:trim($code)"</material>
```

In reality I have about 20 user defined java functions and my XSL has to include 20 namespace entries instead of the 1 I had previously.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "integrated extension functions" (which are the only kind available in Saxon-HE) then there is no connection between namespace URIs and Java class names. You can name your function anything you like.